# How to implement the pause and turn of the transporter in AnyLogic, like in PlantSimulation

Tags: anylogic

How to implement the pause and turn of the transporter in AnyLogic, like in PlantSimulation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2vc5.gif)

I expect to use it normally in MoveByTransporter.
I have tried setting a node with a very small radius and limiting the speed of transporter within that node, but it seems to have no effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wghx.png)
The transporter is still traveling at its original speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TransporterControl` block and its "on enter node" code. This is executed for every transporter on the same agent type as the block whenever it enters a node.

For your case, reduce the speed as needed:
[image]